# Is there a maximum limit of open std::ifstream instances? Problem with > 254 instances

Tags: c++, boost, fstream, ifstream, boost-propertytree

I have a C++ Class with an `std::ifstream` attribute. Every object of this class on creation takes a file path in the constructor, opens the file and using the `std::ifstream` attribute and keeps it open during the lifetime of the object.

Somewhere else in the code, at a later point, I read a `.ini` file using the `boost::property_tree::read_ini` function.

Everything works as it should in the normal case. However, when I create more than 254 instances of above class having the `std::ifstream` attribute, the totally unrelated code of reading the `.ini` file fails and I get a `std::runtime_error` with `"cannot open file"` in the `exception.what()` message.

This makes me wonder if I'm not allowed to keep more than a certain number of open `std::ifstream` references.

Can anyone point out if this is the case or if I'm missing something?

Edit:
- I'm using Windows x64 system

Comment: *This makes me wonder if I'm not allowed to keep more than a certain number of open `std::ifstream` references.* The language does not have any restrictions but OS's do. After all, they don't have unlimited resources.

Comment: What platform? What resource limits? If this is a UNIXy platform, what the output of  `ulimit -n`?

Comment: I'm using a windows 64 bit system using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Keeping > 200 files open??? Ever thought of that your design might be flawed?

Comment: @Aconcagua if you think having 200 files open is a design flaw, apparently you never build a database system.

Comment: @SergeyA If there's a limit for open file descriptors, it would apply for the DMBS as well. So if it relies on, it wouldn't be able to run on any OS imposing such a limit. Pretty sure a non-naive DBMS finds better ways to handle the issue... (Although, admitted, a certain number of open files still will be required.)

Comment: This limit is in the MSVC's standard library implementation, not the OS.  You can increase the limit if necessary.  Details in the older post.